# SSH is disabled prior to local login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I setup a home server (Ubuntu Server 17.04) over the weekend. I configured SSH[0] and ufw[1]. After booting, I am unable to login via SSH until I login locally. Once I (re)connect a monitor and keyboard and login locally, then I can login/logout over SSH indefinitely, even after logging out from my local session.

Last night I was able to login with SSH, and I left the server running. This morning I was unable to login over SSH, even though the computer wasn't rebooted over night. I have `VisualHostKey` enabled in my client SSH config (on macOS), and I can see the ascii art from the server, but then I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

[0] Disable `root` login, disable password login, enable public key login, upload key, change port

[1] Change all `icmp` (ping) rules to `DROP` (ipv4 and ipv6), allow custom SSH port, deny everything else

Comment: I also configured a Plex server on this machine, but I was experiencing the issue before and after setting Plex up, so I don't think its relevant. I can connect to the Plex server without issue (after a fresh reboot or overnight).

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention, but I chose "Encrypted LVM" and let the installer handle partitioning the disk. It seems SSH can't read my home directory to verify my key. I haven't invested to much time/effort into setting up this server, so I'm going to just reinstall *without* encryption.